# cleaning my dataframe (similar lines and \xc3\x28 in the field)

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on dataframe with python.

in my first dataframe df1 i have :

```
+------+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+  
|  ID  |  PUBLICATION TITLE  |    DATE      |      JOURNAL     |
+------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+
|   1            "a"           "01/10/2000"        "book1"     |
|   2            "b"           "09/03/2005"          NaN       |
|  NaN           "b"           "09/03/2005"        "book2      |
|   5            "z"           "21/08/1995"        "book4"     |
|   6            "n"           "15/04/1993"   "book9\xc3\x28"  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here I would like to clean my dataframe but I don't know how to do it in this case.
Indeed there are two points which block me.

The first one is that lines 2 and 3 seems to be the same line because the title of the publication is the same and because I think that the title of the publication is unique to a newspaper

The second point is for the last line one to \xc3\x28.

How can I clean my dataframe in a smart way, to be able to use this code for other daataframe if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should remove the row with `ID = NaN`. This can be done by:

```
df1 = df1[df1['ID'].notna()]
```

Then update the journal of the 2nd row:

```
df1.iloc[1, df1.columns.get_loc('JOURNAL')] = 'book2'
```

Finally, for the entry of `'book9\xc3\x28'`, you can update it by:

```
df1.iloc[4, df1.columns.get_loc('JOURNAL')] = 'book9'
```

Comment: but if I do that I won't have any way to know the name of the newspaper on the line 

| 2 "b" "09/03/2005" NaN | 

Although it seems to be the same as the line 

| NaN "b" "09/03/2005" "book2 |

Comment: @KuRuVIIIII I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What type of encoding are you using.
I recommend using "utf8" encoding for this purpose.

Comment: I loaded a csv file from my local with this command 
df1 = pd.read_csv("publish.csv", header=0, index_col=None, sep=',',  encoding="utf-8") 
and I also tried this command 
df1 = pd.read_csv("publish.csv", header=0, index_col=None, sep=',') 
but the result is the same.

Comment: you can use regular expressions then ```re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', s) ``` and substitute the results of the dataframe. You can also use list comprehension with this like ```df1['JOURNAL'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', x))```

Comment: I imported re, but when I tried you solution with lamda I got this error : 
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Thats because your data has a Null value on index 2. Please try it without null values. remove all null vlaues from dataset.